# Multiple WCF connections in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app that connects with WCF service to load data. I added a Web Service Reference directly from Visual Studio, and runs very well.

But, my problem now is this: I have to connect with different WCF services depending the user who login app.

Exists any way to doing this by code?? I'm using a Xamarin Forms Portable app.

---

**SOLVED:**

Finally, I change the url of the service by code:

```
service = new ServicioWebClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://myurl/wsdl"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I change the url of the service by code:

```
service = new ServicioWebClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://myurl/wsdl"));
```